# How to know next run time of a Pentaho Scheduler?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, pentaho, jobs

How can i calculate next run time of cron (quartz) scheduler? Is there any method, any library which could help me doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call method [getNextValidTimeAfter](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#getNextValidTimeAfter(java.util.Date)) on the given instance of class org.quartz.CronExpression.